# Deleted comments at closed question

Tags: discussion, comments

This question [Why cant we measure the alleged curve of ball earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/524660/) was closed. Before it was closed I had made a relevant comment. After closure my comments disappeared also. Is this the automatic  result of closure? I was able to add the comment again , so closed questions do accept comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, deletion of comments does not automatically happen when a question is closed. I'm surprised you didn't know this. (There is one exception that I know of: when a person votes to close as a duplicate, the system automatically posts a comment with the link to the alleged duplicate question; if the question accumulates enough votes to actually be marked as a duplicate, then that automatic comment will be deleted.)

The comments that were on that question were deleted manually because they seemed to be answering it.

Comment: David , I would appreciate it if the person who removes the comment also leaves the reason for it. I have stated before that at my age, becoming 80 in April, I always check if I remember correctly on commenting or my age is at fault and I imagined it. Also   I thought that two line answers are not really acceptable , are not really answers.but the concepts were. interesting

Comment: I believe this has been brought up before, but we're not always going to remember to leave a new comment explaining why previous comments were deleted. We can try to do that more often, but please do try to get accustomed to the idea that comments may be deleted sometimes without a visible sign. (You can always ask a moderator in chat to confirm whether you've made a comment on a particular post.) Also, there's no minimum length for answers. Anything that answers the question should be posted as an answer (or not at all), _not_ as a comment, even if the answer is short.

Comment: Then do you think the comment by Zachos here should be deleted? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/524619/. I often see answers indicated in comments in short hand, people not desiring to expand, or having no time to do so.. the comments, as the one by Zachos in the link, are very useful for readers.

Comment: Yep. Comments are generally supposed to suggest improvements to the question. Any time you see a comment that doesn't do that, if it answers the question, feel free to advise the commenter that they should post their answer as an answer, and you'd be doing us a favor if you flag those comments as well.

Comment: @DavidZ  In my mind, all of my comments are handles of improving the question, or  having it retracted--which does happen, quickly, virtually invisibly, and comprises my  deepest level of satisfaction... They communicate to the OP: "surely you are familiar with this--are you *sure* you're taking it into account in your question?" Sending  him to the PDG or WP is not answering the question; it is insurance that due diligence is expended on avoiding pointless, avoidable, questions.

Comment: @annav I for one would appreciate it if this site were *not* littered with a bunch of "comments were deleted" comments. One of the key distinguishing features of this site is its (still quite high, though suffering) signal-to-noise ratio. Please, let's not intentionally degrade it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty :they could easily provide a tool to appear in the comments alerts of each user : your comment was deleted because irrelevant",  "because it should be an answer" etc., the way they alert us if there is an answer to our comment. That way the main page would not be cluttered but the user would be alerted, and improve his/her comment submissions according to the policy of the site.

Comment: @annav As I'm sure you're aware, that type of changes to the software is controlled by Stack Overflow Inc, and not by this site's community. I would encourage you to submit that as a feature request on [meta.se], though it's important to note that these types of requests have been having a rather tough time lately - it doesn't seem that SO is very interested in developing those aspects of the software.

Comment: I for one highly disagree with this philosophy of comment deleting. No clearly useful comment should be deleted unless it's been made redundant by other comment, or answer, or perhaps proven to be wrong.